# Linux:Can't read binary file written on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am writing a binary file on Windows (Win7 64bit ,VS2012 64bit project).Read it find on that side.
But if I am trying to read it in a C++ project on Linux (Kubuntu 64bit ,GCC 4.7 64bit proj) .The ifstream fails to open it.In fact,also tried with fopen and it can't open the file either.

I tried to open full 777 permission and open the file in a text editor -that is all fine.

Using the following code to open the file:

```
  bool success = false;
 //trying weith fopen:
  FILE *f = NULL;
  f = fopen("xxx.bin","rb");
  if(f != NULL){
      success = true;
  }
  printf("Stat:%d\n",success);

//trying with ifstream
std::ifstream stream;
stream.open("xxx.bin", std::ios::binary);
success = stream.is_open();
if(!success){
        throw;
}
printf("Stat:%d\n",success);
```

Both fail.

What could be the problem.And what should be taken care of when encoding cross platform binary files.I suppose endianess is not a problem here as both OSs use little endian.

Comment: Are you making sure the filename is case sensitive?

Comment: A binary file is just a blob of bytes. Windows or Linux is irrelevant as long as you don't want to make any sense out of the bytes. If you cannot open it, something is wrong that's basic. The file is probably not where you expect it to be.

Comment: print the error message.

Comment: If that's the real code you tried, note that you didn't close the file with `fclose` before attempting to open it again.  Or if not that, post the *actual* code you tried.

Comment: You can use the function `perror` after `fopen` failed to print the error message which could contain some extra information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie opening at once by 2 streams is not a problem,with other files it works...  Gonna check perror

Comment: @sjdowling  this is it - case sensitive thing... My windows code used on linux didn't take it into account.Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you making sure the filename is case sensitive? –  sjdowling

this is it - case sensitive thing... My windows code used on linux didn't take it into account.Thanks! –  Michael IV